# How to see the progress using ruby-progressbar gem?

Tags: ruby

I am writing a ruby script in which I am running multiple other scripts which take at least 15-20 mins to run. Right now I am displaying a static text on the console that tells user about which process is running and what is the ETA to complete.

Instead of having a static text I want to have a progress bar so that user can see the progress on the screen. Below is the piece of code where I am trying to print the progress bar using `ruby-progressbar` gem while the other script is running.

```
progressbar = ProgressBar.create

t1 = Thread.new do
       other_script=system("sh run_me_first.sh")
end

 t2 = Thread.new do
        progressbar.increment
        sleep 1

        if other_script
           progressbar.stop
        end

 end

 t1.join
 t2.join
```

But it is printing just the following. No progress is shown.

```
   Run_me_first started (it will take approximately 20mins)...
Progress: |                                                                    |
```

Comment: Your `t2` isn't looping - it increments the progress bar once and quits.

Comment: @nneonneo Thank you, that works. But now I am seeing `WARNING: Your progress bar is currently at 100 out of 100 and cannot be incremented.` error. Since I don't have any size or approximate time that how long will `Run_me_first` script will take, I don't know how to initialize the `ProgressBar` object with higher number. Need more guidance on this.

Comment: Please ask that as a new question.